# EAP-TLS for *wired* network not working

Tags: networking

Trying to connect a computer running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (X86-64) to a 802.1X/FreeRADIUS controlled Ethernet network, using self-signed certificate. **PEAP** works perfectly, but I can't get **EAP-TLS** to work.

1. The GUI setup for wired network insists that the private key file (PEM) is unencrypted, and refuse to let me press the "**Apply**" button, even with correct passphrase. I swear that I've already encrypted the private key file using `openssl rsa -aes256` command.
2. Tried to export the private key again as an unencrypted PEM file, the GUI setup accepted this unencrypted private key file, but when I enable connection, it jumps back to off immediately.
3. Command `nmcli conn up <NIC>` gives an error message: "**802.1X supplicant configuration failed**". And there isn't any EAP request packet sent out from the machine.

I'm pretty sure the L2 Switch and FreeRADIUS setup are correct, because `eapol_test` shows SUCCESS using the same certificate/private-key files. And this computer works perfectly using any EAP method other than EAP-TLS.

I've read somewhere that there was a bug similar to this during Ubuntu 14 era. Hard to believe that it still persists after almost 10 years.